# Magento 2.1.5 How to remove zero-only decimal points from the displayed prices, preserving the non-zero one?

Tags: price, magento2.1.5

I'm trying to remove the `.00` part from product pricing. On Category page it can be done with JS, and same on page load for product pages. But, when a user makes attribute selection on a product, the price goes back to showing the `.00` because JS is set to on page load.

Any idea how I could go about simply removing the `.00` by formatting the price itself?

Side note: **I only want to remove the decimal part if price ends in `.00`**, our other customer groups have catalog price rules that give them discounts, and for that we have to keep the decimal values in place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js

```
Just go to 

var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,

in your script and set 

var precision = 0
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: I already try this code in price-utils.js but not working i have use in this line add replace.('.00',' ').below define code 
return pattern.replace('%s', r).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').replace('.00','');    
but in this code remove after load actual price after remove zeros

Comment: Please suggest another solution after loading not shown in old price like this $20.00 instead  only $20